# Python : Importing my custom script in Spyder to use with another script

Tags: python, function, spyder

Hello everyone I am learning Python. While using Spyder I finished writing my own function (test.py) I saved the script in a new folder. In Spyder I made sure to change my working directory to where the test.py is located as well as the PYTHON PATH. Now when I try to import test  it says in the console that there are no modules named 'test'.  Any help will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Alex yeah the problem was I was not working in the same directory as the package I made so I opened up the command prompt in Spyder, went into the correct directory and was able to import/install it with no issues!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/test.py')
import test
```

if you want to `import test` inside of another script, the most sure-fire method is to just have both scripts in the same directory

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I will try it out